# PERL ssh script tty issue

Tags: perl, ssh, sudo, tty, traceroute

I am trying to write a PERL script to ssh to a remote machine and run some tcptraceroutes. I managed to handle the SSH part fine. However tcptraceroute command requires sudo, and here is where I ran into an issue. Example:

```
my (@traces, $stderr, $exit) = $sshCali->cmd(tty => 1, 
"sudo tcptraceroute $endpoint", interactive => 1, debug => 1);
```

When I use tty => 1 system complaints with this error: 
"not a tty"
When I do not use tty => 1 then I get this: 
"sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings; 
use Net::SSH::Perl;

#vars
my $endpoint = 172.31.100.1;
my @traces;
my $sshCali;
my $hostCali = 'remotemachine';
my $cmd = 'sudo traceroute';

warn "Starting SSH Services:...\n";

$sshCali = Net::SSH::Perl->new($hostCali, interactive => 1, debug => 0) or die "Couldnt establish connection!";

$sshCali -> login("user"); # for non-interactive mode;

print "here\n";

my (@traces, $stderr, $exit) = $sshCali->cmd("sudo tcptraceroute $endpoint", interactive => 1, debug => 1);

#my (@traces, $stderr, $exit) = $sshCali->cmd(tty => 1,"$cmd $endpoint", interactive => 1, debug => 1);

print STDERR "STDERR: $stderr\n" if $stderr;
print "command exit w/ code: $exit\n";

$sshCali -> cmd("exit");


print "NOW ..... Printing the array: TRACES\n";
print @traces;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should consider using [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) instead of Net::SSH::Perl. Its documentation contains information about how to use it with `sudo`.

Comment: I think I gave it a try at first, but I will check it again, when I get to work today. Thank you.

Comment: I tried this module but this PERL module is not installed, and I don’t have permissions to install it. Is there any other way of accomplishing this task with PERL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely possible to install a module in your home directory and call it inside your script.  See this node on Perlmonks for exact steps: [Installing Perl modules in home directory](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=128077#permission)